# ExtJS element height in chrome devtool

Tags: css, extjs, combobox, height

I have this combobox of ExtJS. The combo sits in a "form". The calculated height of combo's top-most element is 70px, while in the CSS it is defined as 47px.

[image]

I can't see any effect of changing the height of this combo in CSS and can't find the source if this "70px" height either. Anyone familiar with that strange height mismatch? Is there a way to find the real source of the calculated height?

Comment: Could you reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: Also, before you try, please use the Shortcut Ctrl + Zero to remove any effects from browser zoom. 70px is roughly 47px * 150%...

Comment: @Alexander I cannot reproduce it, since, I guess, the whole theme stands for this mess. My page is not zoomed. Anyway, my question is more about the strange height source in the devtools and the way to find the correct one.